# Unity "Text Mesh Pro UGUI" component rewrites my text! Make it stop?

Tags: unity, gui, text, ui-design, game-component

I'm having this terribly annoying problem where my text is being overwritten by Unity. This Happens regardless of whether I am using tags or not.

Here is what I want to appear (more or less, I don't think this example is using the tag):

[image]

And here is what happens when I try to include a monospace tag:

[image]

Since you might not see it here, the text I inputed is

```
<mspace=64px>A</mspace>
```

This works FINE for regular TMP objects, which the other 3 are (and are using). I am trying to implement dropdown (and left, and up, and right) menus.

You can see that Unity overwrites it as "Option A", like it has a clue what I'm doing. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the tag that you are using.

For dropdown fields, the text of the label is overwritten by the dropdown component based on the selected option. In order to set the text of that label, you should go to the dropdown component and set the text of the selected option (Option A) like so:

[image: example]

Or unlink the Label from the dropdown component, but it is likely that you want it to be linked sinse you are using the DropDown component for a reason I suppose.